# Load post ajax data in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, load

I have the below code.

```
    jQuery(document).on('submit', '#myform', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var formdata = jQuery(this).serialize();
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            data: formdata,
            success: jQuery( "#popup" ).load( this.action + '?' + formdata )
        });
    });
```

What I have works however I think there must be a better (proper way to do this)?

I thought I could load data from my line above in the success  but data is not defined?

Comment: define success as  success: function(data){ ...

Answer (score 1):

Based on the description of [jQuery.load](https://api.jquery.com/load/):

> Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element

It looks like you should just be able to do something like:

```
jQuery(document).on('submit', '#myform', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formdata = jQuery(this).serialize();
    jQuery('#popup').load(this.action, formdata);
});
```

This should take whatever HTML is returned from the server on `this.action` and pop it into your element with `id="popup"`.